# JScroll auto resize in windows size change

Tags: java, swing, autoresize, absolutelayout

How to make the JScroll to auto resize? for example i expand the windows, so the scroll expand together, for Height and Width?

look image,

[image]

for everything i use the AbsoluteLayout, since its more easy to Drag and Drop elements in the screen (Using Eclipse)

i dont know how to make this auto resize possible, but looking the Name of the DefaultLayoult "ABSOLUTE" will  it be impossible in this way??

Comment: `for everything i use the AbsoluteLayout,` - don't use AbsouteLayout! `, since its more easy to Drag and Drop elements in the screen` - it may be easier for painting, but it is not easier for functionality as you have noticed. If you would use the proper layout managers then this functionality will work for you by default. That is why we always recommend using a layout manager. The scrollpane will only work properly when you use a proper layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [GradBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and set the GridBagConstraints attribute "fill" to BOTH